# How to segment images so that the result is just the segmented image (no background whatsoever)

Tags: opencv, machine-learning, computer-vision, image-segmentation

I am working on a computer vision project that involves the segmentation of images. However, I do not want a 'normal' segmentation (like [this](https://paperswithcode.com/media/thumbnails/task/task-0000000885-88f43a92_UVaBSta.jpg)), rather, I want a segmentation that only leaves the desired image itself, without even a blank background (similar to [this](https://www.vicarious.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/captcha_as.png)).

Right now, I am thinking that the background needs to be set to the alpha channel after image segmentation, after which the image can be fed into a probabilistic program. Is that the proper way to approach this, or do I need to perform additional preprocessing to segment the desired image BTW, I am working with `opencv-python`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image you're providing is segmentation results for different approaches.

1. The image at [first image](https://paperswithcode.com/media/thumbnails/task/task-0000000885-88f43a92_UVaBSta.jpg) is the result image of semantic segmentation. In this semantic segmentation task, you have do define which pixel are belonging to which class
2. The image at [second image](https://www.vicarious.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/captcha_as.png) is the result image of hierarchical segmentation. In this hierachical segmentation task, you have to group pixel and find the relationship between them.

So from first image, you have to apply the "hierarchical analyzing", then you will have the result as second image. The easiest approach using opencv is :

1. considering each class as one contour
2. Find the contours hierarchy . Some tut here : [contour hierachy](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d9/d8b/tutorial_py_contours_hierarchy.html)

Hope this help.